# get MySQL command input and output types

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, database-metadata

Is there any way to get a list of the input parameters and their types and output parameters and their types for any MySQL command? I am primarily interested in select statements and stored procedure calls. I don't want to execute the command to get the information.

With Microsoft SQL Server, this information can be obtained from `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set` as described in [New Metadata Discovery Features in SQL Server 2012](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/new-metadata-discovery-features-in-sql-server-2012/).

I am open to any automate-able solutions that I can use. Ideally, it would be a stored procedure I could call or a native library I could wrap.

#### 2015-12-11 Update

Is is possible to prepare a statement and then get the input and output types? For example, I can prepare, execute and deallocate a statement like so:

```
prepare stmt1 * from 'select * guestbook.entries';
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
```

After preparing the statement, is it possible to query for metadata about the statement? The [C API Prepared Statement Type Codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-prepared-statement-type-codes.html) gives me hope. I didn't see anything like that in the .NET API.

The [mysql_stmt_result_metadata](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-result-metadata.html) docs looks really promising:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is anything similar to `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set`. You might have to create your own proc for MySQL.

Comment: I custom proc is an acceptable solution. If you know what the proc would be, please add it as an answer.

Comment: have a read about getting this information from the information_schema : [stored routines metadata](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines-metadata.html)